# PL/SQL error with cursor, ERROR ORA-06550

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, procedure, oracle18c

I'm studying PL/SQL and I'm trying to create a procedure, but I'm having problems with the cursor and I don't know what it is, if you can help with my code I'll be grateful.

take a look in my code

```
DECLARE
TYPE T_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
V_CURSOR T_CURSOR;
V_STATION STATION_DATA%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN V_CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM STATION_DATA;
   FETCH V_CURSOR INTO V_STATION;
    EXIT WHEN V_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
    'STATION NUMBER = '||V_STATION.STATION_NUMBER||
    'REPORT CODE = '||V_STATION.REPORT_CODE||
    'YEAR = '||V_STATION.YEAR||
    'MONTH = '||V_STATION.MONTH||
    'DAY = ' ||V_STATION.DAY||
    'DEW POINT = '||V_STATION.DEW_POINT||
    'STATION PRESSURE = '||V_STATION.STATION_PRESSURE||
    'VISIBILITY = '||V_STATION.VISIBILITY||
    'WIND SPEED = '||V_STATION.WIND_SPEED||
    'PRECIPATION = '||V_STATION.PRECIPATION||
    'TEMPERATURE = '||V_STATION.TEMPERATURE||
    'SNOW DEPTH = '||V_STATION.SNOW_DEPTH||
    'FOG = '||V_STATION.FOG||
    'RAIN = '||V_STATION.RAIN||
    'HAIL = '||V_STATION.HAIL||
    'THUNDER = '||V_STATION.THUNDER||
    'TORNADO = '||V_STATION.TORNADO
    );
    END LOOP    ;
  CLOSE V_CURSOR ;
 END ;
/
```

Comment: `select * from user_errors` will show you the actual error message(s). Then you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61592945/edit) that add that important information.

Comment: this error should give you the row and column numbers where the error raised. I suppose, a buffer overflow might raise.

Comment: You forgot to use the `LOOP` statement but you are closing it using `END LOOP`. Please use `LOOP` before `FETCH V_CURSOR INTO V_STATION;` and check if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing the `LOOP` statement and also some code that is not needed.

You need something like this (see inline comments):

```
DECLARE
--    TYPE T_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR; -- YOU DON'T NEED THIS
    V_CURSOR    SYS_REFCURSOR; -- USE SYS_REFCURSOR
    V_STATION   STATION_DATA%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN V_CURSOR FOR SELECT *
                        FROM STATION_DATA;
    LOOP -- ADDED THIS
        FETCH V_CURSOR INTO V_STATION;
        EXIT WHEN V_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
                'STATION NUMBER = '||V_STATION.STATION_NUMBER||
                'REPORT CODE = '||V_STATION.REPORT_CODE||
                'YEAR = '||V_STATION.YEAR||
                'MONTH = '||V_STATION.MONTH||
                'DAY = ' ||V_STATION.DAY||
                'DEW POINT = '||V_STATION.DEW_POINT||
                'STATION PRESSURE = '||V_STATION.STATION_PRESSURE||
                'VISIBILITY = '||V_STATION.VISIBILITY||
                'WIND SPEED = '||V_STATION.WIND_SPEED||
                'PRECIPATION = '||V_STATION.PRECIPATION||
                'TEMPERATURE = '||V_STATION.TEMPERATURE||
                'SNOW DEPTH = '||V_STATION.SNOW_DEPTH||
                'FOG = '||V_STATION.FOG||
                'RAIN = '||V_STATION.RAIN||
                'HAIL = '||V_STATION.HAIL||
                'THUNDER = '||V_STATION.THUNDER||
                'TORNADO = '||V_STATION.TORNADO
                );
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE V_CURSOR;
END;
/
```